# IntelliJ - Javadocs for my library not showing when referenced by another project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have what seems like a pretty simple use case here: I've created a Java library, and published it to Maven local, and I'm referencing that library from another project. However, in the other project, IntelliJ is not showing the Javadocs, or really any useful information about my library function including parameter names. I suspect I've missed something basic because of my relative inexperience in Java but a lot of searching has turned up nothing particularly useful and it seems like I've followed the instructions for enabling Javadocs.

I should note that third-party libraries from Maven Central are working as expected. I'm only seeing this problem with libraries that we have created internally that in Maven local.

EDIT: I've discovered this is only a problem in Maven local -- when the library is deployed to Azure Artifacts it works as expected. So this does seem to be something specific to Maven local.

First, I'll explain exactly what I'm seeing. In my library I have

```
public interface SomeInterface {
  /**
   * ...Javadocs...
   */
   void doSomething(String someParameterName, boolean anotherParameterName);
```

Elsewhere within the same library, this works as expected. I declare `SomeInterface s;`, I type `s.doSomething(...`, I press Ctrl+Q on `doSomething`, I see the expected documentation.

Then I build this library and publish to Maven local. I create a new project and reference this library. In the new project I declare `SomeInterface s;`, I type `s.doSomething(...` ... but this time, IntelliJ shows the function definition as `void doSomething(String s, boolean b)`, with no other documentation. This is true of every function in my library ... all parameters show as `String s`, `boolean b`, `T t`, etc. If I go to definition (Ctrl+Alt+B), IntelliJ shows the decompiled class file, and shows the correct names of those parameters. So I'm not sure why I'm getting `String s`.

I'm using IntelliJ 2020.1.2 and Gradle 6.1 to build both the library and the project referencing it.

The build.gradle for the library looks like this

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group '<my group id>'
version '0.4'

java {
    withSourcesJar()
    withJavadocJar()
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        MyLib(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "${group}"
            artifactId 'my-lib'
            version "${version}"
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

I looked into the .m2 directory after publishing the library and I can confirm that the base JAR is present along with a -javadoc.jar and a -sources.jar.

I tried referencing my library from a new, empty project with no other dependencies. No luck. This is the build.gradle of the referencing project.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: '<my group id>', name: 'my-lib', version: '0.4'
}
```